# The Display Text is null while converting video to text using Postman API

Tags: postman, azure-cognitive-services, speech-to-text, azure-speech

I am using the cognitive services using Postman API but the display text is not appearing.
[image: output after adding all the parameter]

params-
language: en-US

headers:
Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: key
Content-Type: audio/wav

body-
binary: selected file

Authorization-
bearer Token: Token generated from cognitive service

I have changed the content-Type as audio/mp4, audio/mp3, audio/vnd.wave and changed the video length and as well converted to audio.

Answer (score 1):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I got the same response when I tried with the mp3 file format.

[image]

According to this [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/rest-speech-to-text-short#audio-formats) the audio format either may be WAV or OGG .

When I tried with WAV file format in Postman it executed with text successfully.

[image]

For Mp3 and other compressed input audio, you need to use Speech SDK.

**Reference:**
[How to use compressed input audio - Speech service - Azure Cognitive Services | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-codec-compressed-audio-input-streams?tabs=windows%2Cdebian%2Cjava-android%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-python)